# Define the minimal configuration for a program

Tags: deployment, exe, release

So I have my .exe ready to deploy, and for distribution, I need to know the minimal requirements for my program to run on a machine... and I really don't know how to do that.

Is there a way to know that ? Some kind of benchmark ? Or must I just set things as I think it'll work ?
Maybe should I just buy all existing components until I find the minimal ? :')

Well, thanks for your answers.

Comment: what requirements? What "things" do you want to set?

Comment: Do you even know what you want to do?

Comment: Does your program not run? What do you think it might require? Libraries?

Comment: @tobi303 The configuration needed in order to run the program. You know, what you usually find on the back of the games, saying minimal CPU, GPU, RAM...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Start by seeing the first Windows' version you can deploy on (Windows XP? Vista?).

If your program is cpu or gpu intensive, and has a fixed time loop (eg. game) then you'll have to do benchmarks.

You should look at several old vs new CPUs/GPUs and trying to "guess" based on online specs posted online what the minimal requirement is. For example, if your program can't run on an old cpu, but runs blazingly fast on a new one, try to find the model that -barely- runs it, which will obviously be one somewhere in the middle.

If your program requires other special things, specify them (eg. USB 3.0, controllers supported...).

Otherwise, if your program loads slower but doesn't have runtime issues, the minimum specs should be indicative of a reasonable loading time (a minute seems to be the standard now, sadly).

Additionally, if your program is memory hungry (both hard drive or RAM), you must indicate this.

- For hard drive memory, simply state your program size, along with the files included with it.
- For RAM, use a profiler - it will tell you how much memory your program is using.

I've completely skipped over the fact that, in some computers, the bottleneck might be the cpu, and it might be the gpu in others. You need to know which is the bottleneck to make your judgement.

To find out is a rather simple process - remove expensive gpu operations (lower texture resolutions, turn off shaders). If the program still runs slowly, then the bottleneck is the cpu.

> edit: this is a simplification of the problem and hardware is a little more complicated than this (slower multi-core cpus vs faster one-core cpus vary their performance depending on how many cores a program uses and how / a program may require a gpu to have less memory but more processing power, or the opposite... even heat dissipation can affect component efficiency: your program might run fine for 20 minutes but start to slow down if the cpu isn't cooled down properly), but "minimal hardware requirements" aren't exactly precise so this method is appropriate.

tl;dr of the spoiler:

> In short, there are so many factors that affect performance that you can't measure it, so just a rough estimation is good.

Comment: The thing is : I don't know how to know each thing.
I do not have any XP machine nor Vista, so how do I know if my program runs under these OS ?

Same for benchmarks, I don't know what I can use to do that ? Is there some kind of program allowing us to do it ?

Comment: @LeTiroir I can't help you much if you don't know. If you're compiling using visual studio you should have a minimum of Vista. Ask people that have these versions to test it for you. To run benchmarks, I'll have to know more about your program - is it a game? Does it have framerate, or what does it do?

Comment: It is a game, and yeah it has framerate, why ?

Comment: @LeTiroir Display the framerate - use that as a benchmarking tool. If the fps starts to dip below the minimum during most of the game, then the CPU or GPU in that machine is causing a bottleneck. In that case, determine which of the two is causing it and proceed as explained in my answer. If you run into more problems, I'll try to answer them.